# link_to and remote => true + jquery ajax:success

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I have a number of links on one page doing remote calls to update the content on the page. Everything works perfectly so I have decided to add a overlay to elements which have content loading so it gives the customer some visual reference that something is going on.

So on each of the links where I want to show an overlay I add a class plus through the data attribute I pass in the div I want the overlay on. Here is some example code.

```
<div id="content">Old Content</div>
<%= link_to "Update Content", some_path, :class => 'ajax_trigger', :remote => true, 'data-target' => 'content' %>
```

Ok so when clicked it runs off and loads the data with respond_to block format.js where I replace the content ie,

```
$("#content").html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => '/shared/content')) %>")
```

And like I have said all works great.  Ok so I have a global bit of JS (coffee script) to do the overlay ie.

```
  $(".ajax_trigger").live("ajax:beforeSend", (evt, data, status, xhr) ->

    # Get target div to add overlay
    target = $(this).data('target')
    $t = $("#"+target)

    # Update CSS for Overlay
    $("#overlay").css
      opacity: 0.7
      top: $t.offset().top
      left: $t.offset().left
      width: $t.outerWidth()
      height: $t.outerHeight()

    # Update Image for Overlay
    $("#img-load").css
      top: ($t.height() / 2)
      left: ($t.width() / 2)

    # Show Overlay
    $("#overlay").fadeIn()

  ).live("ajax:success", (evt, data, status, xhr) ->
    $("#overlay").fadeOut()
  ).live "ajax:error", (evt, data, status, xhr) ->
    alert "Failed!"
```

This works perfect for 2 items on the page but for one it shows the overlay but does not hide it. I am getting no errors as of course the ajax:alert with give me a warning.  The content loads in perfect on the overlay so again its all fine.

I cant see how there is a difference and why it will not hide even though I got a good response and content replaced.

Any suggestions how I can debug this?

Comment: What is different about the one element that doesn't work properly?

Comment: Its just a different but of content. But as stressed it loads fine.

Comment: Is the element which triggered the ajax request also getting replaced as the result of the ajax call? If yes then probably problem lies there. There is a issue with jquery-rails not firing events on elements not longer in DOM, I couldn't find the link with some basic googling tough.

Comment: Aghh thats a good point. I recon thats the issue as in the case of the non finishing one the content is being replaced. What would be best to search on to find a solution?

Comment: @Lee I tried with "jquery rails ajax callbacks not firing", but it didn't show up the page where I read about the issue. PS: mention someone in the comment if you address it to someone.

Answer (score 0):

I can't tell what your problem is just from the description.  Have you used a JavaScript debugger such as those in Firebug or Chrome Developer Tools?  Find your script, set a break point, click on the troublesome link, and step through the code.